# Add aditional class to get_avatar when showing image

Tags: images, avatar

I want to add bootstrap img-responsive and img-rounded classes to avatar image when displaying one. But for some reason the class is not displayed when using `get_avatar`.

By WordPress codex there is an attributes list that you can use in `get_avatar` to alter the function but my doesn't pickup class array list.

Here is current code that i use.

```
get_avatar( $current_user->user_email, 128, null, null, array('class' => array('img-responsive', 'img-rounded') ) );
```

By explanation last parameter is arguments array in which you can use `size` , `height` , `width` etc... among those is `class` which can be array or string.

So i tried a few combinations

```
$args = array(
   'class' => 'img-responsive img-rounded'
 );
get_avatar( $current_user->user_email, 128, null, null, $args );
```

I also tried

```
$args = array(
 'class' => array( 'img-responsive', 'img-rounded');
);
```

But for some reason class is not accepted.

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Are there any plugins or something using `get_avatar` filter?

Comment: Nothing that can make a problem to the function, i searched through the whole project and only plugin that uses `get_avatar` is jetpack plugin but i doubt that this can make a problem. What combination did you tried and works?

Comment: I copied your first line of code, changed the user id. That's it. Did you try with other themes?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No @Rev i didn't, now when i have some free time again i continue to work on my theme and stumbled on this problem, i came back here to see for any other answers but nothing. I still can't figure out why it's not accepting the args.

Comment: `function.php` filter solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542796/adding-class-to-gravatar-img-in-wordpress

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem, too. Here's the solution for version 4.7.3 if anyone comes across this.

```
get_avatar( $id_or_email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), $size = '60', $default, $alt, $args = array( 'class' => array( 'd-block', 'mx-auto' ) ) );
```

or shorter version

```
get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), '60', $default, $alt, array( 'class' => array( 'd-block', 'mx-auto' ) ) );
```

For some reason, all the parameters have to be present or it doesn't work.

This method, unlike the functions.php method, will not alter get_avatar globally. So you can have different classes like "post-author" or "comments-author".

Answer (score 1):

Try this one..

```
<?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('ID'), $args['image_size'], '', 'alt', array('class' => 'avatar_class') ); ?>
```

Example:

```
<?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('ID'), $args['96'], '', 'avatar', array('class' => 'myclass') ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any chance you are using the plugin WP User Avatar. I have just run into this where it seems that it is filtering the get_avatar function but not passing the last $args argument through that would contain the class info.

I'm going to start looking for a different solution to uploading custom avatars...