# Class parameter in get_avatar args doesn't get added to output

Tags: functions, images, themes

I try to add custom class on get avatar in comment walker

```
get_avatar( $comment, $args['avatar_size'], '', '', array('class' => 'myclass') );
```

But class doesn’t show in source code.
Thx

Edit :
Output

```
<img src="...default.png" width="48" height="48" alt="Avatar" class="avatar avatar-48wp-user-avatar wp-user-avatar-48 alignnone photo avatar-default">
```

Comment: what gets output?

Comment: The default avatar img

Comment: sorry, i wasn't clear - please can you add the HTML that gets output to the question

Comment: Are you sure it's this line that is used to render the avatar? Are you `echo`ing it, as this function just returns a value, and the class parameter looks correct

Comment: Added output result

Comment: This is referenced and solution given here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/224288/add-aditional-class-to-get-avatar-when-showing-image

Comment: I already read this post but doesn’t work :/

Comment: Ah, that's annoying. If you're sure this is the line of code which is creating this output then the other likely answer is that some other plugin or code is filtering the output. Did you try disabling all other plugins? And pls see question above?

Comment: Thx. It’s “wp-user-avatar” plug-in  that prevents class addition.